# Fedex shipping for india not working

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, fedex

I have created magento store for India and i have enabled FedEx shipping method from the system configuration but it will not showing in checkout shipping method section. my client has registered in FedEx with country india and i also have added the shipping method origin country india and city delhi but still it is not displaying on the checkout shipping method sections.

Can any one let me out from this issues?

I have found bellow error in my log file.

```
2015-06-24T07:57:02+00:00 ERR (3): 
SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'AccountNumber' property in /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php:461
Stack trace:
#0 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php(461): SoapClient->__call('getRates', Array)
#1 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php(461): SoapClient->getRates(Array)
#2 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php(487): Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex->_doRatesRequest('SMART_POST')
#3 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php(186): Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex->_getQuotes()
#4 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php(209): Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex->collectRates(Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#5 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php(129): Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping->collectCarrierRates('fedex', Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#6 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(944): Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping->collectRates(Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#7 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(875): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->requestShippingRates()
#8 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php(155): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectShippingRates()
#9 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(1013): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping->collect(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#10 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1331): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectTotals()
#11 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(458): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()
#12 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(144): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
#13 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
#14 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#15 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/buyboxon/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/buyboxon/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Double check your configuration of the FedEx shipping, ensure no extra spaces in values, etc.  Also what version of PHP are you using, I see the tag CE 1.9.0.1 for Magento.

Comment: I have use magento 1.9.1.1

Comment: @Muk i am on magento 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Check you settings for all correct values and for india specific :

Update the wsdl files in Magento/Fedex/Carrier.php file

In order for the India to India domestic shipping to work you need to add in a PurposeOfShipment type to the request. This line is not standard in Magento's code for Fedex shipping. That line will be added into CustomsClearanceDetail header as a child under CommercialInvoice then a line under that is Purposewhich can have any value that PurposeOfShipment has.

Here is an example of the request I used that returned proper shipping estimates for India to India shipping.

```
'CustomsClearanceDetail' => array(
     'CommercialInvoice' => array(
       'Purpose' => "SOLD"
    )
),
```

The rates for some reason only work with production keys for me.Try the production keys if you are also having some problem with test.

Comment: where to add this array can you suggest the exact path. I am using Magento 1.9.2. and facing the same issue when origin is India.